# What is the best VPN software to watch Netflix?

Tags: vpn, vpn-server

It looks like Netflix continue its "hard work" to block vpn servers not only outside us... So my current vpn service started to show error while streaming netflix smth like "oops, something go wrong..." and I wonder who has a real experience with a stable vpn vs netflix solution? I have found some workarounds like this https://www.vpnhint.com/blog/expressvpn-netflix-not-working/ but none seems to solve the issue.

Comment: You are looking for a VPN service/host right? The software, on the other side, is pretty standard.

Comment: In view of https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/are-hosting-recommendation-requests-on-topic, I put this question on hold until you clarify how particular *software* might be a solution, as opposed to a particular *host*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using expressvpn with USA - Los Angeles 3 server and doesn't have any issues with Netflix. Have a try it should work.

Comment: Welcome aboard. Couldn't you at least have posted a URL, rather than expecting everyone who reads this to Google?